# Are Google Play's featured Android apps different for different regions?

Tags: android, google-play

I've written an Android app that is specifically for Muslims. Obviously I don't expect the Google team to feature my app in the United States, but it would make sense to have it be featured in majority Muslim countries like Malaysia, Indonesia, Saudi Arabia, etc. Does anyone know if the Google Play Store has different featured apps for different regions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The featured apps in Google Play are those which the Google Play team consider as model citizens adhering to various Android app design guidelines and best practices (for example, they apply the Action Bar UI pattern in a proper way; they handle the back stack consistently .. etc). I do not recollect coming across any mention about them being region-specific. You could watch this [Google I/O 2011](http://youtu.be/GxU8N21wfrM) video to be absolutely sure though.

Having said that, purely from observation, I would say that the "Featured" tab in the Google Play Store is *not* region-specific. I live in India, and I have seen featured apps that make little sense to an Indian user.

However, it looks like some of the other tabs ("Top New Free", "Top New Paid", "Trending") etc do seem to be region-aware. I do see some apps in those tabs which are highly specific to India; and I would be surprised if they sold so much as to be on the global "trending" list.

Comment: Thanks. That's dissapointing, but I guess now I don't have to worry about the promotional text+graphic :)

Comment: Look at it this way: You just saved yourself 1024 x 500 worth of work :P

Comment: An update: I just noticed that the CricBuzz app has been featured on the Google PlayStore. Could you verify whether you see this app in your region too? This app deals with cricket - a sport which has following only in certain pockets of the world; and I suspect it might have been "Featured" specifically for India region.

Comment: Well I can't find it anywhere in the featured apps section. So it does seem to be region specific. On the other hand, my Google Play store has a featured section for "T-Mobile Top Picks" (my cell carrier) so it seems obvious that the featured apps must be *somewhat* different.